Can I use API certified oil in my 2011 Volkswagen Jetta?
I have a 2011 Volkswagen Jetta 2.5 SEL. I recently have decided to start doing my own oil changes due to the increasing prices of having it changed elsewhere.
I know that the oil that has been used in the vehicle is Mobil 1 Full Synthetic 5W-30 European Car Formula. I would like to put in Kirkland Signature 5W-30 Full Synthetic Motor Oil.
However, the following two sources are at odds:
My vehicle manual states:

The engine oil used must conform to exact specifications.
...
For gasoline engines use VW 504 00, VW 502 00
...
At the time this manual was printed, the engine oils available in the U.S. that meet these Volkswagen standards are "synthetic" oils. This does not mean, however, that any "synthetic" engine oils will meet Volkswagen standards. Always use an approved oil that expressly complies with the Volkswagen oil quality standard that applies to your vehicles engine.

My repair manual (Chilton) which was obviously written and printed after my vehicle manual states the following:

Listed here are the manufacturer recommendations at the time this manual was written. Manufacturers occasionally upgrade their fluid and lubricant specifications, so check with your local auto parts store for current recommendations.
...
Engine Oil: API - SM/SL; ACEA A2/A3 synthetic

The Kirkland oil has the following details on the back: API SP, SN PLUS, SM and ILSAC GF-6A, GF-5 which suggests that my repair manual states this oil is acceptable.
Is the cost savings worth it, and is this oil acceptable? I have to drive much further to get the European blend, and it is significantly more expensive for me.
